# SharePoint - Check if item is edited by another user

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, deadlock

Hope someone could help me.

We use SharePoint 2007 Foundation and I have an applicatin designed in C#, part of it is CAML query which returns items for Order Transportation, based on output it creates an email attachement and send it. Then new status is being set for each item like 'Transport Ordered'.

The problem is:

If someone is editig same item which application setting up new status it throws following error, email with attachment is sent, but status remains unchanged and in next run are duplicity items.

```
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction (Process ID 89) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.HasMoreRows()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQuery(Boolean& bSucceed)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListItemDataWithCallback(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureListItemsData()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.GetItemIndexById(Int32 id)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.GetItemById(Int32 id)
   at ImportExportTool.Program.OrderTransportation(SPList planningList, SPField statusField) in c:\Users\MacProWin\OneDrive\Work\ImportExportTool v30 - source code\Program.cs:line 368
```

could anyone tell me how to check if Item is edited by another user then force close it or maybe suggest better solution?

Here is the part of code where the new status is being set:

```
foreach (int orderItemId in orderedItemsIds)
                {

                    SPListItem orderedItem = planningList.Items.GetItemById(orderItemId);
                    Common.Log(String.Format("Status Doprava Objednana is now set to Item: '{0}'", orderItemId));
                    SPFieldMultiChoiceValue statuses = new SPFieldMultiChoiceValue(orderedItem[Properties.Settings.Default.StatusFieldName].ToString());

                    statuses.Add("Doprava objednána");
                    orderedItem[Properties.Settings.Default.StatusFieldName] = statuses;

                    orderedItem.Update();
                }
```

Thank you very much.

Marek

Comment: Do you have check in and check out enabled in the items.

Comment: I dont, because we process a large amount of Items and each item is edited 4-5 times since we consider it as closed so I cannot ask users to approve each change. Basically its too time consuming. Best solution would be if I can recognize opened item and skip it to next run.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible, The checking in and checking out will stop other from editing the document at the same time. I understand this will increase user editing time however the duplicity would seem like a bigger issue to me

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no way how to detect "open" item. You can check modified field but it only shows you when it was updated last time.

From architect perspective you should combine you 4-5 updates ideally into single update operation to minimize the deadlock problem. You should also check current value in your field (compare actual value and value you want to write) prevent from doing unnecessary updates.

From technical perspective (solving problem that occurred) you should do your operation first handle potential transaction exception repeating your operation (what is suggested in exception message). And in case of success send notification.

Comment: You're right. Just changed code a bit to first handle transaction and in case of success it will send an email.